# how use createwriteStream with javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream, fs

how i can send file for that the server read it  with fs.createwriteStream();

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');

http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    // This opens up the writeable stream to `output`
    var writeStream = fs.createWriteStream('./output');
    // This pipes the POST data to the file
    req.pipe(writeStream);
    req.on('end', function () {
        res.end('ok upload file');
    });
    // This is here incase any errors occur
    writeStream.on('error', function (err) {
        console.log(err);
    });
}).listen(8080);
```

i use this command with console linux:
curl --upload-file hello.txt 127.0.0.1:3000 and work ok but i don't know how send file with url

somebody know?

Comment: i see this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zyf-TdYz1fo and think that can

Answer (score -1):

curl -i -F name=test -F filedata=@localfile.jpg 127.0.0.1:3000

Comment: but with javascript friend